# How Convert Plain Text to Json with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert this list below to json or js object, using Javascript. But searching the internet, I couldn't find how to do this.

```
Afghanistan- 132
South Africa - 7560
Albania - 175
Germany - 230
Andorra - 370
```

this is an abbreviated version of the list, the original is much longer, making it impracticable to do it by hand.

**the expected output after converting to a json or js object should be something like:**

```
[
    {
       "id": 132,
       "country_name":"Afghanistan"
    },
    {
       "id": 7560,
       "country_name":"South Africa"
    },
    {
       "id": 175,
       "country_name":"Albania"
    },
    {
       "id": 230,
       "country_name":"Germany"
    },
    {
       "id": 370,
       "country_name":"Andorra"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: I don't see any JSON here, just an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Split the plaintext list by the newline character. This gives you an array of strings like ["Afghanistan- 132", "South Africa - 7560", ...].

Next, map through that list and split each string to retrieve the bit before and after the dash.

Then it's just a case of returning an object in each map iteration to get an array of objects, trimming the split values to remove any unwanted whitespace.

Once you have that, to turn it into a useable JSON string, just use JSON.stringify() on it.

```js
const stringList = `Afghanistan- 132
South Africa - 7560
Albania - 175
Germany - 230
Andorra - 370`

const mappedList = stringList.split("\n").map(item => {
    const splitItem = item.split('-');
    return {id: splitItem[1].trim(), country_name: splitItem[0].trim()}
});

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(mappedList);

console.log(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yes I realize that, but without stating it explicitly the OP will continue to conflate js Object with JSON which is a pervasive misconception in beginner questions on SO

Comment: Understood, I edited my comment to add that in at the end. Thank you.

Comment: thanks bro, this really solved my problem. It's so easy to solve, but really useful. Thanks!